# Bootstrap inline form buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Image showing the problem]

As shown in the image, my buttons are not inline with eachother and the cancel button is far bigger than it should be.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <%= button_tag t('btn.save'), class: 'btn btn-brand-color', type: 'submit' %>
    <%= link_to t('btn.cancel'), :back, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to have the two buttons next to each other preferably by using already existing bootstrap classes.

Comment: This isn't a rails issue - the button_tag code just outputs a <button></button> with the options you provide.  These 2 object, button and link should be displaying inline natively with vanilla bootstrap. So it looks like you've changed something, specifically, you have an `a` declaration in css with a width of 100%

Comment: Yes it's not a rails issue- I merely added it as a tag due to the fact that I'm using rails code to.

Comment: and yes you were correct- I found a declaration that had set the default button to width: 100%. thank you for pointing that out :) feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment - you have a link (a) declaration which is set to 100%.

- tip -- might be easiest to use the browser inspector to find out which class and in which css file are overriding your intention.

For others in the future: If there is any doubt about whether a class is vanilla bootstrap, or something you've inadvertently overriding a class you hadn't intended to, you can view bootstrap's native behavior by inspecting the html row or element, right clicking - then click on  Copy as HTML

In this questions example that output would be

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-brand-color"><span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.btn.save">Save</span></button>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:history.back()"><span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.btn.cancel">Cancel</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Paste that into http://www.bootply.com/new and click Run -- it's a good indicator of style interference (also Bootply lets you change versions of bootstrap to match your own.

Answer (score 0):

I never used ruby-on-rails before. But if you get this, maybe you should create a new CSS class and include `display: inline-block` on the button & make sure the button with are not set `width: 100%`.